# XSL: how to use document() to read xml files in a folder

Tags: xslt

I need to compare xml files from two folders and collect those xml elements that only show up in one of the xml file.

The xml files in two folder has same file name.
Below is the sample of what I want to do:

old/booklist1.xml

```
<books>
    <book @type="fiction">
        <isn>12345678</isn>  
        <name>xxxx</name>
    </book>
</books>
```

new/booklist1.xml

```
<books>
    <book @type="fiction">
        <isn>12345678</isn>  
        <name>xxxx</name>
    </book>
    <book @type="history">
        <isn>23456789</isn>  
        <name>yyyyy</name>
    </book>
</books>
```

I will need the output of the booklist1.xml as the below:

```
<books>
    <book @type="history">
        <isn>23456789</isn>  
        <name>yyyyy</name>
    </book>
</books>
```

I have below findDiff.xsl that works when I specify / hardcode the xml file name:

```
<xsl:key name="book" match="book" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/books">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="book[not(key('book', ., document('old_booklist1.xml')))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The fidDiff.xsl current is associated with new/booklist1.xml and I copied the old/booklist1.xml to the same folder with new/booklist1.xml and made the name as old_booklist1.xml and above xsl works with the hard coded uri.
I have to loop throw xml file in folder new and then compare it with the same named xml file in folder old.

I am thinking to use the following way to build the xml file URI:

1. loop in the new and get the file uri
2. build the file uri for xml file in old folder

   <xsl:variable name="xmlPath" select="document-uri()"/>

   <xsl:variable name="compareWithPath" select=" replace($xmlFilePath, 'new', 'old')"/>

then pass the compareWithPath to below template:

```
<xsl:template match="/books">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="book[not(key('book',., document($compareWithPath)))]"></xsl:copy-of>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

But I got the error that The system cannot find the file specified
file:/C:/Users/phyllis/Documents/old/booklist1.xml

Michael Kay mentioned that we can convert the file name to URI and use doc() or document() to load it. I build the filename URI exactly the same way that I got from document-uri(). What am I wrong here?

The converted file URI looks like this:

```
<compareWithPath>file:/C:/Users/phyllis/Documents/old/booklist1.xml</compareWithPath>
```

Returns false when check above file URI using:

```
<fileExist><xsl:value-of select="doc-available($compareWithPath)"/></fileExist>
```

Comment: So where do you "loop" through files in a folder? Are you using Saxon's `uri-collection('old?select=*.xml')` or where/how exactly do you try to find and load the URIs?

Comment: I am not thinking to use collection() in my case. there are 50,000+ xml files and biggest is 50M in my folders. I tried collection() and it put all of the xmls under a node-set() and that is huge. I want to apply the template on each xml file pair so I am thinking to use groovy  folder.eachFile { file -> "call findDiff.xsl to output the diff elements directly" } so I am with one xml file in folder new, then using document($uri) to open same xml file in folder old inside of findDiff.xsl.  Or is there a better solution for my case? much appreciated!

Comment: There might be less memory consumption if you use a version of Saxon (9.8 or later) that supports XSLT/XPath 3 where in addition to the `collection` function there is the `uri-collection` function which only gives you the URI of the files in the collection but doesn't pull them in all together. Additionally, in the commercial editions of Saxon you have a `discard-document` function to avoid memory problems I think.

Comment: But if you are doing the folder processing in Groovy that's probably fine, perhaps add a tag for that and show some minimal but complete samples so that someone knowledgeable in that are can say whether there is a reason that the file is not found. Or perhaps first run Saxon from the command line to see whether there is a difference. It will be hard to judge from the details shown so far why the `doc-available` fails.

Comment: I am using Saxon 9.8 home version. I just started step by step so first step is to use the xsl to collect only difference and it was stuck there by passing in document-uri. Let me try uri-collection funtion and maybe only xsl can solve my problem if it can pull one xml file at a time. I was thinking to use Groovy only because I was using collection() and it pulls all the xmls together. Thank you Martin for the information. Let me try it out and update results.

Comment: Once you have the file access working, I would look at whether you can't improve the key you have with `<xsl:key name="book" match="book" use="." />`, given that `book` seems to have various child elements and whitespace any key on the complete contents can easily break by a change in indentation or white-space stripping. Perhaps a composite key on the particular elements you need to use to identify a book is a better approach in XSLT 3.

Comment: The file access issue was caused by permission. I didn't know that there is no permission to access the folder belongs to my user though I am working on the VM everyday eh..  :<  @Martin - You are right, the indentation/whitespace broke the key. Is there a way to strip out those stuff before creating the key?  I need to compare the whole element in my real case.

Comment: Just tried out the `uri-collection()`. It scans the folder and returns the uri for each file in a specified folder. So now I can use the `uri-collection()` to generate a xml node that holds all the xml files in a folder and then open the related file pair from two folders to compare. Is this the correct approach? Well I have to build a better `key()` to do diff...

Comment: Or I have to put all the files on my Linux server and using `dos2unix *.xml` and `sed  -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\(<\/[^>]\+>\|<[^>]\+\/>\)\(\n\)\?[^<]\+</\1</g' *.xml` to strip out all the hassles before I run the xsl on the folder. It would be perfect do all the steps in the xslt without involve other separated steps. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you have `uri-collection()` and want to process each document use e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="uri-collection() ! doc(.)"/>` or e.g. `<xsl:iterate select="uri-collection() ! doc(.)">...</xsl:iterate>` or for-each with the same select if wanted/needed.

Comment: Perhaps ask that key problem in a new, separate question will all details, I would still think that in XSLT 3 using a composite key with e.g. `<xsl:key name="book" match="book" composite="yes" use="*" />` and `book[not(key('book', *, document($compareWithPath)))]` is a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below xsl code works well for my problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="3.0">
   
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
   
    <xsl:key name="book" match="book" composite="yes" use="*"/>
   
    <xsl:template match="books">
        <xsl:param name="compareWith"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of
                select="book[not(key('book', *, document($compareWith)))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:iterate select="uri-collection('new') ! doc(.)">
                <xsl:variable name="fileUri" select=" concat('update/', tokenize( document-uri(.),'/')[last()])"/>
                <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$fileUri}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="books">
                        <xsl:with-param name="compareWith" select="concat('old/', tokenize( document-uri(.),'/')[last()])"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:iterate>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Only a `key()` is able to eliminate the duplicates, find diff, compare file, etc. Never thought it could be so easy to solve this kind of problem using xsl but once and once xsl proved his power when it comes to xml.

`<xsl:iterate select="uri-collection() ! doc(.)">...</xsl:iterate>` iterate through `uri-collection()` makes it easy to loop through the folders.